# How to display client-side validation error without asp-validation-for?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to customize the way the client-side validation is displayed on my form.

I don't want to use the `asp-validation-for` tags so they don't display with the control. I'd rather show these in the `ValidationSummary` control with the other errors or some other centralized place.

Is there a way to show the client-side model.field errors anywhere other than using a `asp-validation-for` tag?

Comment: ValidationSummary does exactly that. I don't understand where is your problem.

Comment: Your example helped me. I didn't have it within the form tag so only server-side errors were showing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use validation summary tag helper with attribute `asp-validation-summary="All"`

```
<form asp-controller="Demo" asp-action="RegisterValidation" method="post">
    <div asp-validation-summary="All"></div>
</form>
```

Ιt's important that the validation summary tag helper is placed **inside** the `<form>` tag!

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-6.0#the-validation-summary-tag-helper

Comment: I had mine outside the form tag which apparently causes client-side errors not to show.